# Can I modify a path in an Akamai redirect?

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, akamai

I need to create an Akamai 301 redirect rule.

I want to redirect all traffic from:
http://www.example.com/subdirectory/*

To:
http://subdomain.example.com/*

I'm able to do it easily through the control center as a "Relative Redirect Change Hostname only" - but I need the subdirectory stripped out of the target URL. I still need the rest of the path intact.

So example.com/subdirectory/file.html should redirect to subdomain.example.com/file.html.

I can get this to work in htaccess at the web server level, but I need to have it happen at Akamai.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "modify outgoing request path" behavior in the configuration and select "remove part of incoming request path" for first occurrence only. This should do the trick.